# Laravel Livewire: Passing option value onChange of Select input

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

I am trying to pass a value from the `<option>` of my `<select>` input to my livewire controller component and echo the value.

**Livewire Blade View Component:**

```
{!! Form::select('goals',$goals_plucked,null,[
    'placeholder' => trans('classes.backend.forms.select_goals'),
    'class' => 'custom-select',
    'id' => 'goals',
    'wire:change' => "goals(this.val)",
]) !!}
```

This get's me an output of null in my Livewire Controller Component

**Livewire Controller Component**

```
public $goals;

public function goals($goals)
{
    dd($goals);
}
```

After watching some tutorials. I also tried using `'wire:change' => "goals($event.target.value)",` which gave me an error of Undefined variable $event, obviously because it was not defined in main controller. I am not sure what am I doing wrong here.

**What I am trying to do:** Trying to create a flow just like select country then select state and then select city. via livewire. Before selecting a country the inputs of the select state and city won't be visible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried below code and it worked for me well. Just had to make sure I use normal html form inputs and dynamically add options to it by foreach loop. Also used `mount()` function for getting getting values and id's for select dropdowns.

**Livewire Blade View Component:**

```
<select wire:model="goal" name="goal" class="form-control" required>
    <option value="">
        {!! trans('classes.backend.forms.select_goals') !!}
    </option>
    @foreach ($goals as $goal)
        <option value="{{ $goal->id }}">{{ $goal->goals }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

**Livewire controller component**

```
public $goals;
public $goal;

public function mount()
{
    $this->goals = Goals::all()->isActive();
}

public function updatedGoal($value)
{
    dd($value);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

just give wire:model="variable_name" to select in front end.

and in livewire controller there should be a public variable with same name. it will automatically get the value on select value change.

below is the example of same

```
 <select class="custom-select border-0 shadow-none" id="enquiry_for" wire:model="enquiry_for">
      <option value="1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="3">Option 3</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: I tried `'wire:model' => "goals",` & `'wire:model' => $goals,` but nothing happened also tried putting `'wire:model' => "$goals",` which gave me an error `Property [$] not found on component`

Comment: is the select in livewire view?

Comment: 'wire:model' => "goals". If you are receiving an error with $ means that binding is working. So, you need to write in the right syntax attr

Comment: @HardikSisodia are you writing wire:model in single quote. if yes remove it.

Comment: It is `wire:model="goal"`.  You have `wire:model => 'goal'`. It is `model = property` not `model => property`. I screwed this many times.